# Python/Scipy - Integrate with Quad Along Axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numerical-integration, quad

I have a 2D array.  The "xy" plane is a grid from (-1,-1) to (1,1).  I want to compute and integral at each point where the function depends on the coordinates of the point.

I know that with discrete data I can use simps or trapz and specify an axis to integrate along (see example).   Is this possible with scipy.integrate.quad without using an ugly loop as shown below?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.integrate

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 10)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 10)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

z = np.linspace(1, 10, 100)

# Integrate discrete values using simps
def func(z):
   return (X - z) / ((X - z)**2. + Y**2)
res1 = sp.integrate.simps(func(z.reshape(-1, 1, 1)), z, axis=0)
print(res1)

# Integrate the function using quad at each point in the xy plane
res2 = np.zeros(X.shape)
for i in range(res2.shape[0]):
   for j in range(res2.shape[1]):
      def func2(z):
         return (X[i,j] - z) / ((X[i,j] - z)**2. + Y[i,j]**2)
      res2[i,j] = sp.integrate.quad(func2, 1, 10)[0]
print(res2)
```

Comment: Have you tried the answer so far?

Comment: Yes, I did.  The answers that I got matched my example above, so it does seem to work! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Cubature method](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Cubature) from Prof. Steven Johnson, which I [wrapped using Cython](https://github.com/saullocastro/cubature), you can achieve the integration at once doing:

```
import numpy as np

from cubature import cubature

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 10)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 10)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

z = np.linspace(1, 10, 100)

def func(z):
   return (X.ravel() - z) / ((X.ravel() - z)**2. + Y.ravel()**2)

res = cubature(1, func, np.array([1.]), np.array([10.]))[0].reshape(X.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using linearly spaced points is not very efficient. A better idea would be to turn to quadrature schemes for quadrilaterals, e.g., [here](https://github.com/nschloe/quadrature#quadrilateral). For example:

```
import numpy
import quadpy

def f(x):
   return (x[0] - 1) / ((x[0] - 1)**2 + x[1]**2)

quad = numpy.array([
    [-1, -1],
    [+1, -1],
    [+1, +1],
    [-1, +1],
    ])

scheme = quadpy.quadrilateral.Stroud(5)

val = quadpy.quadrilateral.integrate(f, quad, scheme)
```

[image]